# Arduino: how to use object of other class as arguments of my library?

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm breaking my head trying to use Servo.h inside of a library I made. The compiler consistently gives me the same error, as if it does not recognize the class, which is included in my library.

I am trying to make a new class, one of it's properties is a Servo object, which I should pass in the constructor. No matter how I try, I keep receiving the same error message when trying to compile my sketch:

> In file included from /home/nezah/Arduino/My
>   sketches/CameraShutter/CameraShutter.ino:8:0:
>   /home/nezah/Arduino/libraries/Shutter/Shutter.h:13:19: error: expected
>   ')' before '*' token
>        Shutter(Servo *servo);

It seems that the include statement is ok, as I get a different message if I mess it to go wrong or remove it completely. I already tried to change "" for <> and even copied the source in a folder and use the full path. No change as far as I don't mess it (on purpose). I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504211/is-it-possible-to-include-a-library-from-another-library-using-the-arduino-ide).

I also tried to pass it as a pointer, using `Shutter(Servo* servo)`, `Shutter(Servo *servo)` and `Shutter(Servo& servo)`. Same error message.

In some arduino.cc forum I read that I rather forget it and avoid using libraries inside other libraries, but I bet this is possible.

Is there anybody so kind as to give me some hints on how to do this?

I leave you part of my .h and .cpp of the library I'm trying to write (which, by the way, turns a servo into a physical button presser but with burst capability).

```
 /*
 * Shutter.h - Library to make a photocamera shutter out of a servo
 *   alternatively it could press any physical button with a servo.
 */

#ifndef Shutter
#define Shutter
#include "Servo.h"

class Shutter {
  public:
    Shutter(Servo *servo);
    Servo getServo();

    void shut();
  private:
    Servo _servo;        
}

#endif
```

And here is my .cpp:

```
/*
  Shutter.cpp - Library for flashing Shutter code.
  Created by David A. Mellis, November 2, 2007.
  Released into the public domain.
*/

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "Servo.h"
#include "Shutter.h"

Shutter::Shutter(Servo *servo) {
    _servo = servo;
}
```

NOTE: If I remove some code and take away the "Servo" part of the constructor, I get an error message on the "getServo()" code. The problem seems to be that the compiler does not recognize "Servo" as a valid type inside my library.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the constructor of your class you are passing a pointer of the type Servo, so you must store that value in another pointer. To do this you must change:

*.h

```
#ifndef SHUTTER_H
#define SHUTTER_H
#include "Servo.h"

class Shutter {
  public:
    Shutter(Servo *servo);
    Servo *getServo() const;

    void shut();
  private:
    Servo *_servo;        
}

#endif
```

*.cpp

```
Shutter::Shutter(Servo *servo) {
    _servo = servo;
}


Servo *Shutter::getServo() const
{
    return _servo;
}
```

Use:

```
Servo servo;
Shutter shuter(&servo)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your help! I tried what you told me, but still get the same error message: `In file included from /home/nezah/Arduino/My sketches/CameraShutter/CameraShutter.ino:1:0:
/home/nezah/Arduino/libraries/Shutter/Shutter.h:12:19: error: expected ')' before '*' token
     Shutter(Servo *servo);`. I would ask: is there something I have to do to the IDE to include the library Servo? I have used it in sketches before, but not in libraries.

Comment: Your answer helped me to correct the code, which was a mess, but didn't really solve the problem. Anyway gave me the hint to find the solution, I think. Thanks again!!

Comment: You could share your complete code (* .ino, * .h, * .cpp) via github, dropbox or similar.

Comment: After I finished and commented the code of the library, I uploaded it to GitHub: https://github.com/elnezah/Shutter

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was that the class name and the #ifndef marker was the same, so there was a name conflict somehow. It is well explained in this thread: [How to properly use a header file to be a complete class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128559/how-to-properly-use-a-header-file-to-be-a-complete-class)

After fixing this, it compiled well.